# PHP if statement in SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I am trying to involve an if statement in my SQL query in my PHP code. Basically, I want to say "if $var is not 0, add the WHERE clause, but if $var is 0, don't add it".

Code below, doesn't seem to be working. Help is greatly appreciated!

```
$var = $_GET["var"];

$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table ".if($var != 0) { echo "WHERE var = '%s'," }."
  if($var != 0) { mysql_real_escape_string($var) });

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

***Update***

I ultimately decided that since I will be using multiple conditions for multiple variables, it was best to do the following:

```
$var = $_GET["var"];
$string ='';
if ($var != 0) {
  $string = "WHERE var =". $var . " ";
}

$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table ". $string.");

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Now I can use as many variables as I want and add additional clauses to the SQL statement.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have an `if` expression inside string concatentation. Also, you're missing the trailing `"`.

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table ". $var != 0 ? "WHERE var = '%s'" : "");
```

Also, `mysql_real_escape_string()` doesn't take the variable by reference, so the modified string is returned:

```
if($var != 0) { $var = mysql_real_escape_string($var) });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table%s", $var != 0 ? " WHERE var = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($var) . "'" : "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use PHP for this; use the database.

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $database);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE (:select <> 0 AND column = :value)');
$stmt->execute(array(':select' => $var, ':value' => $var));
```

Comment: It's a completely MySQL way. Would you please comment an example result that it might produce? I want to learn this query. Thank you

Comment: That depends on the data you have: that query tells the database to only collect rows where both `column` is exactly equal to `$value` and a user specified parameter is not equal to zero. The point is that database is more than just a giant hash table for storing data; they're also capable of filtering and operating on massive amounts of data very efficiently -- much more so than PHP is.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = $_GET["var"];
$string ='';
if ($var != 0) {
  $string = "WHERE var =". $var . " ";
}

$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table ". $string.");

$result = mysql_query($query);
```